# How do I join 2 tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, inner-join

I have two tables as follows that the id values of the `tblBranch` table in the `tblPost` table are in the Cityid, catid, Desid columns
How can I join these two tables together to see the values of cityid, catid, Desid?

```
tblBranch                  tblPost
----------                 -----------
id                         id
Name                       title
                           cityid
                           catid
                           Desid
```

Comment: tblBranch have 2 cloumn id,Name

Comment: tblPost have5 cloumn id,title,cityid,catid,desid, that cityid,catid and desid value is in tblBranch

Comment: The three columns you want in your output are all from the `tblPost` table - why do you even want to join?? Doesn't make a lot of sense.....

Comment: @SoroshFt Are you saying that you need to see the `Name` in `tblBranch` corresponding to each `cityId`, `catid` and `Desid` ?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It isn't clear what you've tried and where you ran into trouble.

Comment: @marc_s:i want to see the name of cityid,catid,Desid in tblpost but  I dont know how to join 2 table that see them

Answer (score 0):

When you are join tables, you are bringing/combine TWO TABLES data rows
and their columns into ONE BIG TABLE base on the MATCHING JOIN COLUMNS.

Here is example of inner join:

```
tblDepartment
--------------
id_Dept                    NameDept 
1                          Math
2                          Physic 

tblTeacher
----------
id_Teacher                 FullName             id_Dept 
1                          Smith Adam            1
2                          John Doe              1
3                          Marry Doe             2
```

**EXAMPLE 01: No rows filter**

select TC.id_Teacher, TC.FullName, TC.id_Dept, TD.NameDept from tblTeacher TC inner join tblDepartment TD on **TC.id_Dept = TD.id_Dept**

Result ONE BIG TABLE OF JOINING TABLES

```
id_Teacher                FullName           id_Dept         NameDept
1                         Smith Adam          1              Math 
2                         John Doe            1              Math 
3                         Marry Doe           2              Physic
```

**EXAMPLE 02: With rows filter**

Result ONE BIG TABLE OF JOINING TABLES with SQL where clause to limit smaller set of data rows return

select TC.id_Teacher, TC.FullName, TC.id_Dept, TD.NameDept from tblTeacher TC inner join tblDepartment TD on **TC.id_Dept = TD.id_Dept**
where **TC.id_Dept = 2**

```
id_Teacher                FullName            id_Dept         NameDept
3                         Marry Doe            2               Physic
```

You can use the above example to see WHAT COLUMNS your table should join to return result with BIG TABLE

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly, you want to take `CityId`, `CatId` and `DesId` from `tblPost`, and for each of them, you want to join to the `tblBranch` table and show the `Name` for that `Id` - correct?

In that case, you need a query like this:

```
SELECT
    CityId, 
    CityName = brCity.Name,
    CatId,
    CatName = brCat.Name,
    DesId,
    DesName = brDes.Name
FROM
    tblPost p
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tblBranch brCity ON p.CityId = brCity.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tblBranch brCat ON p.CatId = brCat.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tblBranch brDes ON p.DesId = brDes.Id
```

Basically, you need to have **three joins** - one for each of the `Id` in your `tblPost` table.

I chose to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to avoid eliminating a row completely, if one of the `Id` cannot be found/matched in the `tblBranch` table.